# How to make an UIButton optional using storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard

I need to make a Button optional based on data coming from the server.
It's easy when building UI programmatically. Like,

```
if ( flag == 1)
   {
       // Build the UIButton
   }
```

But I am new to storyboard and company wants to build the UI this way. So I was wondering how to make the button optional? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add additional information like what you tried and why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

In your .h file declare your property

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *yourBtn;
```

Link this property to your button in storyboard

In your .m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super ViewDidLoad];
 [self.yourBtn setHidden:YES];
}
```

Later on in your code if you need to enable your button just call

```
[self.yourBtn setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Makes my day 1 in new company much easier. Thank you Panayot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just trying to hide/show a button based on that condition:

```
[button setHidden:NO];
```